# Where do I go to edit the Search Bar in a drupal site?

Tags: drupal

Where do I go to edit the Search Bar in a drupal site?

Answer (score 0):

1st way: Use drupal [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/6/hook_form_alter)

2nd way: Create search-block.tpl.php in theme folder
with following code

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>'print_r(get_defined_vars(), 1) .'</pre>');
```

now you can see all variables you can use in this template

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the template.

If you decide to change it then copy the template to /sites/default/themes and make the changes there.